# regenerate csrf token after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, csrf

How to regenerate a token's input after ajax request, so i don't need to reload the page,
here's my php code to generate a token

```
<?php 
class Token {   
public static function generate() {
    return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
}
public static function check($token){
    if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token']){ 
        unset($_SESSION['token']);                  
        return true;        
    }
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

and here's my jQuery code to send an ajax request

```
function load() {   
    $('#load-data').load('process/karyawan/load.php');  
}


function insert(){
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);     
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: 'process/karyawan/insert.php',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result){              
                load();
            }

        }
    });
});
}
```

and here's my form

```
<form action="" method="post">          
        <div class="kiri">
            <div class="inp">   
                <input type="text" name="nama_karyawan" placeholder="Nama Karyawan" class="form-control nama_karyawan">
            </div>
            <div class="inp">                   
                <textarea class="form-control" name="alamat_karyawan" rows="5" placeholder="Alamat Karyawan"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kanan">
            <div class="inp">   
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="inp">   
                <input type="text" name="telepon_karyawan" class="form-control" placeholder="Telepon Karyawan">
            </div>
            <div class="inp">   
                <input name="akses" class="form-control" value="Admin" readonly>
                <div class="error-msg err05"></div>
            </div>                              
            <div class="inp">
                <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Simpan" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12">
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=Token::generate();?>">
            </div>
        </div>              
    </form>
```

And here's my load.php file

```
 <?php 

session_start();

require_once('../../classes/Config.php');
require_once('../../classes/Database.php');
require_once('../../classes/Query.php');
require_once '../../classes/ErrorHandler.php';
require_once '../../classes/Validator.php';
require_once '../../classes/Token.php';

$connection = new Database($host, $username, $password, $database);
$main = new Query($connection);

$table = 'karyawan';
$selectData = $main->select($table);

while($fetchData = $selectData->fetch_object()){
    if(@$_SESSION['owner']){
        $delete = '<a href="?page=deleteKaryawan&id_karyawan='.$fetchData->id_karyawan.'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
        $button = '<td class="text-center">'.$delete.'</td>';
    }else{
        $button = null;
    }
    echo '<tr>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->id_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->nama_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->alamat_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->telepon_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->akses.'</td>
            '.$button.'     
        </tr>';
}
?>
```

For first request the code is running well, but for the second request I think it wouldn't be running well anymore because I've unset the token.. can someone give me an advice to regenerate a token after ajax request ? thank you

Comment: In your `insert.php`, after calling `Token::check()`, could you `Token::generate()` again and send it to let Javascript change the `<input name="token">` field ? What does your Javascript `load()` ?

Comment: my Javascript load() is like this: $('#load-data').load('process/karyawan/load.php');  which is the load.php is loading the content. could I Token::generate() in ../load.php so the token always regenerate automatically ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But, if you want that your form works another time, without reloading the page, you have to send the new token to your Javascript, and update the token field.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that, honestly I didn't get any idea about how to send the new token to my javascript.

Comment: Could you please post your `update.php` in your question ?

Comment: load.php did you mean??

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it's deleted

Comment: In your `load.php`, why your `session_start();` is called after `Token::generate()`?

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry that's my mistake again, actually the form and the PHP code is in the different file, but I make mistake putting them into one code..

Comment: I've been thinking your advice about to send the new token to my javascript, and Token::generate() after sending the request, then trying to edit the value of <input type='hidden' name='token'> and I think it works...
Thank you so much for your advice

Comment: I've just posted an anwser... The code is not tested, but I hope it could helps you.

Comment: And your posted code is running well, now I have 2 options for this case.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're `unset` your token, the next validation will fail. You have to regenerate a new one after `check` and update your HTML token' field.

First, in your JS `insert()`, add `"json"` datatype.

Then, in your success function, update the field.

```
function insert(){
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);     
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: 'process/karyawan/insert.php',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json", // NEW
        success: function(result){
               $("input[name=token]").val(result.token); // NEW              
                load();
            }

        }
    });
});
}
```

And in your update.php :

```
session_start();
// check and to stuff...
// then
$new_token = Token::generate(); // generate a new token

echo json_encode(['token' => $new_token]); // send to JS
die;
```